# using encodebin in a gstreamer pipeline

Tags: android, c, gstreamer, omap

I have a gstreamer pipeline

```
appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! encodebin ! filesink location=default.raw
```

This pipeline fetches raw yuv-420 frames, of width 1280 and height 720 with the help of appsrc plugin, and push it to decodebin. The encodebin encodes it into h264 and the filesink will dump it into a file.

But this pipeline is not working as I am not specifying the profile for encodebin. 
I am working on android with gstreamer, the platform I'm using is OMAP4460, I want to make use of the hardware encoder. But I don't know to which profile I should set the encodebin.

If someone knows about the profile of encodebin, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't specify a profile on the command line.

Have a look here for inspiration :

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-editing-services/tree/tests/check/ges/integration.c#n95

and there :

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-editing-services/tree/ges/ges-pipeline.c#n844

Have a nice day !

Comment: I am trying from a pipeline written in c